# How does the radius work in Trilateration

Tags: trilateration

I've been trying to understand the trilateration algorithm based on the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilateration). As of now, I have a system where I have the distance of 3 sensors wrt my position and i have the exact GPS coordinates of those 3 points.

How do I include the radius?

Comment: I am trying to conceptually understand what the radius does

Comment: Based on your latest question on the same issue -- http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110051/trilateration-with-gps-coordinates -- you appear possibly to confuse geographic (lat, lon) and projected (N, E) coords. Are you at least clear on those?

Comment: If the answer below (including the linked answers) doesn't answer your question, please edit your question to include *much more detail* on what you understand and don't understand.

Answer (score 2):

The distance from sensor to target is the radius. That radius defines a sphere around the sensor. The point where three spheres from three sensors intersect is the 3D position of the target.

A somewhat better (less mathematical, more conceptual) explanation of trilateration is [at this web page](http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/EMAT6680Fa05/Schultz/6690/Barn_GPS/Barn_GPS.html). Some useful GIS.SE questions that also cover the basics and provide additional details:

- [Differences between triangulation and trilateration?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17344/what-is-the-difference-between-triangulation-and-trilateration)
- [Trilateration using 3 latitude and longitude points, and 3 distances](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66/trilateration-using-3-latitude-and-longitude-points-and-3-distances).
- [This answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/97501/multilateration-code/98100#98100) to a question about multilateration link to additional discussion

Comment: How do i get the sphere for my sensor? I mean, it's just a beacon that I know it's exact 2d coordinates and i know the distance to the beacon via RSSI

Comment: The distance to the beacon is the radius of the sphere.

Comment: I was wondering also. I see many explanation on this being done for 3 points. Are there any example on say N number of points? I only saw a matlab example, but I want actual mathematical equations if possible.

Comment: I can't seem to find any examples. How does this actually work, do i like try all combinations but with trilateration and get an average? Say like Points 1,2,3,4 i do a trilat on 1,2,3..1,3,4..2,1,3..etc.

then i get an average?

Comment: With n > 3 points, it's called multilateration. I believe a least squares approach is most common, but the precise math is getting beyond my knowledge (and the last link above will lead to some good in-depth discussions)